# authlogic crashes with infinite recursion

Tags: ruby-on-rails, recursion, authlogic, infinite-loop

I have some trouble with using authlogic in my rails app, so I began using the blank example from [github.com/binarylogic/authlogic_example](http://github.com/binarylogic/authlogic_example) which doesn't work either.

I spent a day installing ruby 1.9.1 and 1.8 and jruby1.8, neither did work. The fun thing is that another rails app worked on my server. That said, I just cannot see where the code breaks or where the difference is. Here's the output that gives shared/log/mongrel_debug/threads.log:

```
Mon Oct 12 19:23:53 +0200 2009 REQUEST /favicon.ico
0.0.0.0:7102 -- THREADS: 1 -----
 KEYS:
  -- #<Thread:0x7ffe28347fc8>: [:started_on, :__recursive_key__]
```

After some time after the request it times out with a 500. Am I right assuming that it's an infitite recursion in some piece of code?

My server config is:

```
Linux xxxxxx 2.6.28-11-server #42-Ubuntu SMP Fri Apr 17 02:45:36 UTC 2009 x86_64
ruby 1.8.7 (2008-08-11 patchlevel 72) [x86_64-linux]
gem -v: 1.3.5
rails 2.3.4 (any lower version doesn't change it)
```

So far it doesn't depend on the database or the rails version. The only thing that enables the app again is commenting out the #acts_as_authenticated, so I assume that there's some kind of trouble with authlogic and my server conf. Locally it still works (OSX 10.6.1)

I searched google for some hours and built an authlogic app from scratch. If you have any idea what else I could search on or what I could check out, give me a hint!

Thanks a lot in advance!
Till

Comment: Alright, I just deployed on another server - that worked.

I still have no clue why this breaks on the first machine. Thanks for reading anyway!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My coworker has another explanation:

`config.cache_classes = true`

Setting it to false helps it.

Answer (score 1):

Finally I found a solution:

the database name and user had an underscore in it and the password had some special chars in it. Setting it to an easier one solved it.